# Which Python modules are pre-installed in FME?

Tags: python, fme-form

I'm writing a script to be used in a `PythonCaller`-transformer in FME Workbench. I'm wondering which modules/packages are already installed during the installation of FME WB itself, and which ones I should require the user of my workspace to install via the `pip` installer. The only [documentation](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Desktop/Workbench/Installing-Python-Packages.htm) I could find did not mention pre-installed modules.

I'm using the modules `requests`, `BeatifulSoup`, `re`, `pandas`, and `numpy`. I think re and numpy might already be installed, I don't know how to check that.

So which Python modules are installed with FME Workbench?

Comment: What version of FME are you using and which Python interpreter are you using?

Comment: My FME version is V.2021.2.4, the Python version is the default one of that FME version. I guess that is Python 3.7 or higher

Comment: If you already have FME installed, why can't you list the packages yourself?

Comment: I'm waiting for the IT department to install FME in my VM, so I was blind coding. That's why I can't check. But I thought the question might be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the Python language in its most basic form comes with the [*The Python Standard Library*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). Every GIS software with a Python module (like QGIS, ArcGIS, or FME) will have these modules installed.
On this page, you can select your Python version and see which base-python packages are installed.

Alternatively, if you have FME installed, navigate to the directory (`.\FME\`) where FME is installed and find your Python modules in: `Plugins\Python`.